# How to access a[m][n] 2D array using double pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

How to access a[m][n] 2D array using double pointer?

I dont't no why **b can't be used to access 2D array value?

I want to do it without changing "int **b = num;"

------------------------------correct------------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int num[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},
                     {5,6,7,8},
                     {9,10,11,12}};
    
    printf("num[1][2] = %d ", *(*(num+1)+2)); //num[1][2] = 7
}
```

------------------------------incorrect----------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
 
int main() {
    int num[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},
                     {5,6,7,8},
                     {9,10,11,12}};
    int **b = num;
    
    printf("%d ", *(*(b+1)+2)); // Segmentation fault
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going on. Then think about what the code is trying to do. Good way to learn about pointers

Comment: The compiler warns you that `int **b = num;` is wrong. There is no way that dereferencing will know the width of the inner dimension, which is needed to index the 2d array.

Comment: [Compile error](https://godbolt.org/z/vT5coTe5h).

Comment: Because pointers and arrays aren't the same thing.

Comment: You don't. An array decays to a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. A 2D array decays to a pointer to a 1D array. A 3D array will decay to a pointer to a 2D array, etc...

Comment: Note: Lying to the compiler with a sufficiently broad cast will appear to work, compile, but fail at runtime because `int **b` will expect `b[0]` to be an `int*` and not the `int` that's actually sitting in memory.

Comment: Because `T[N}` can be converted to `T*` beginners often assume that implies that `T[N][M]` can be converted to `T**`, it's a logical extension right? Actually no, it's completely different thing. `T[N][M]` converts to `T(*)[M]`. In English an array of T can be converted to a pointer to T, so an array of array of T can be converted to a pointer to an array of T, **not** a pointer to a pointer of T.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to do it without changing "int **b = num;"

That's a problem, because the type of the expression `num` isn't `int **`, it's `int (*)[4]`.

You'd need to change that to

```
int (*b)[4] = num;
```

in order for your code to work.

Answer (score 2):

This record

```
int **b = num;
```

is incorrect because there are used pointers of incompatible pointer types. The type of the expression `num` used as an initializer is `int ( * )[4]`. That is the array designator `num` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int[4]` - the type of elements of the array.

So instead you could write

```
int ( *b )[4] = num;

printf("%d ", *(*(b+1)+2));
```

Otherwise if you will write for example

```
int **b = ( int ** )num;
```

then dereferencing the pointer `b` like `*b` you access the memory extent occupied by the array `num`. But the extent does not contain a pointer in its beginning. It contains elements of the array. So this expression `**b` will invoke undefined behavior.

To make it more clear consider the following C demonstration program. I used the type `unsigned long long` instead of the type `int` to provide the equality of pointer sizes and integer sizes on 64-bit systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "sizeof( unsigned long long )   = %zu\n",
            sizeof( unsigned long long ) );

    printf( "sizeof( unsigned long long * ) = %zu\n",
            sizeof( unsigned long long * ) );

    unsigned long long num[1][4]  =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    };

    unsigned long long **b = ( unsigned long long ** )num;

    printf( "b   = %p\n", ( void * )b );
    printf( "num = %p\n", ( void * )num );
    printf( "*b        = %p\n", ( void * )*b );                           
    printf( "num[0][0] = %#llx\n", num[0][0] );                           
}
```

The program output might look like

```
sizeof( unsigned long long )   = 8
sizeof( unsigned long long * ) = 8
b   = 0x7ffe6a832a20
num = 0x7ffe6a832a20
*b        = 0x1
num[0][0] = 0x1
```

As you can see the expression `*b` contains the value of the first element of the two-dimensional array that is `1`. So the expression `**b` will try to access the memory at the address `1` that invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because pointers and arrays aren't the same thing.

Here's what a pointer to a pointer looks like in memory:

```
address         value
...
0x12345678      0x90909090 <- pointer to pointer to int (stores address of pointer to int)
...
0x90909090      0xaaaaaaac <- pointer to int (stores address of int)
...
0xaaaaaaac      0x00000064 <- int (stores some number)
...
```

Here's a 2d array of ints (this time I wrote the values in decimal) and a pointer to the array.

```
address         value
...
0x12000000      1  <- num[0][0]
0x12000004      2  <- num[0][1]
0x12000008      3  <- num[0][2]
0x1200000c      4  <- num[0][3]
0x12000010      5  <- num[1][0]
0x12000014      6  <- num[1][1]
0x12000018      7  <- ... you get the idea ...
0x1200001c      8
0x12000020      9
0x12000024      10
0x12000028      11
0x1200002c      12 <- num[2][3]
...
0x55554444      0x12000000 <- pointer to array (stores address of array)
...
```

Here we have 48 bytes (12x4) and those bytes are the array, and another variable which holds the number 0x12000000.

In C code, what type could that variable be? It could be `int*` (pointer to the first int), it could be `int(*)[4]` (pointer to an array of 4 ints i.e. the first row) or it could be `int(*)[3][4]` (pointer to the whole array). But it *absolutely couldn't* be `int**` because that would be a pointer to an `int*`, and that would mean at address 0x12000000 there would be some number that would be the address of an int, but that number is 1, which isn't a valid address of anything, at least in this example.

If you do need to adapt between an array like `int num[3][4]` and a pointer like `int **b`, your only choice is to make up this extra array of pointers, and `b` can point to that.

```
address         value
...
0x12000000      1  <- num[0][0]
0x12000004      2  <- num[0][1]
0x12000008      3  <- num[0][2]
0x1200000c      4  <- num[0][3]
0x12000010      5  <- num[1][0]
0x12000014      6  <- num[1][1]
0x12000018      7  <- ... you get the idea ...
0x1200001c      8
0x12000020      9
0x12000024      10
0x12000028      11
0x1200002c      12 <- num[2][3]
...
0x55554444      0xa1230000 <- pointer to array of pointers
...
0xa1230000      0x12000000
0xa1230004      0x12000010
0xa1230008      0x12000020
...
```

i.e.

```
int *thingThatBCanPointTo[3] = {&num[0][0], &num[1][0], &num[2][0]};
int **b = &thingThatBCanPointTo[0];
```

or for short

```
int *thingThatBCanPointTo[3] = {num[0], num[1], num[2]};
int **b = thingThatBCanPointTo;
```